# T-SQL - XML Path clause not returning result set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, for-xml-path

Thanks for your response. Unfortunately your code did not help me. Basically, I wanted to get the xml result set from the below query and want to display that in a html table format.Then I want to send the dataset to the client through email. Below is the stored procedure I have written for that.
EXEC dbo.usp_SFDCGradeComparison

```
Alter PROCEDURE dbo.usp_SFDCGradeComparison
AS
Begin
Drop table if exists #GradeREport
Select 
GR.EnrollMent EnrollMent_Year_New__c
,GR.SCH_Id SCH_Id
,GR.Name SchoolName
,GR.Reporting__c
,SY.SchoolYear SchoolYear
,SY.SchoolID SchoolID 
, SY.CTEGrades CTEGrades
,Case When  RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(GR.Reporting__c,';',''))) 
      = RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(SY.CTEGrades,',','')))
    Then 'Matched'
    Else 'NOT Matched' END As Comments
from #SFDC_GradeReport GR
Full Outer Join #CoreSchoolYear SY
on GR.SCH_Id = SY.SchoolID 
and RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(GR.Reporting__c,';','')))  = 
RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(SY.CTEGrades,',','')))
Where (GR.SCH_Id is null OR SY.SchoolID is  null) 
And GR.SCH_Id <> '005'
And ((RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(SY.CTEGrades,',',''))) IS not NULL ` When I execute the script, it returns the rows in SSMS as I mentioned below. Where as in XML Path its not returning the same result set.
```

EnrollMent SCH_Id  Name    Reporting__c    SchoolYear  SchoolID    CTEGrades   Comments
2018-2019   1056    ABC School  6;7;8;9;10;11;12    NULL    NULL    NULL    NOT Matched
2018-2019   2355    XYZ School  8;9 NULL    NULL    NULL    NOT Matched
2018-2019   1555    Career  9;10;   NULL    NULL    NULL    NOT Matched
2018-2019   1777    Business School 9;10;   NULL    NULL    NULL    NOT Matched
2018-2019   15555   busines school of Florida   9;10;   NULL    NULL    NULL    NOT Matched
2018-2019   2589    Business School of Wisconsin    9;10;   NULL    NULL    NULL    NOT Matched
2018-2019   9999    HS Online Program   9;10;   NULL    NULL    NULL    NOT Matched

My expected output

2018-20191056>ABC School9;10;11;12NOT Matched   2018-2019>2355>XYZ School8;9;10;NOT Matched

But My output is

here`
OR RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(GR.Reporting__c,';','')))  IS not NULL))
order by SCH_Id, SchoolID
For xml Path('tr'), type,root('root')

SET NOCOUNT ON

```
 DECLARE  @profilename varchar(100) ='';
 DECLARE  @to varchar(200) =  ''; 
 DECLARE  @subject varchar(100) ='';
 DECLARE     @body varchar(max) = NULL;
 DECLARE     @bodyhtml varchar(max) = NULL;
 Declare @SuccessMessage varchar(80) = 'No record found'

set @body = cast( (
select td = CAST(s.EnrollMent_Year_New__c as varchar(30)) +'</td><td>'  + 
 CAST(s.SCH_Id as varchar(30) )  + '</td><td>'  + CAST(s.Name AS 
 VARCHAR(30)) + '</td><td>' + CAST(s.Reporting__c AS VARCHAR(80)) + '</td> 
 <td>' + CAST(s.SchoolYear AS VARCHAR(120)) + '</td><td>' + 
 CAST(s.SchoolID AS VARCHAR(200)) + '</td><td>' + CAST(s.CTEGrades AS 
 VARCHAR(80)) + '</td><td>' + CAST(s.Comments AS VARCHAR(80)) + '</td>' 
 from ( Select 
            GR.EnrollMent 
            ,GR.SCH_Id 
            ,GR.Name 
            ,GR.Reporting__c 
            ,SY.SchoolYear 
            ,SY.SchoolID 
            , SY.CTEGrades CTEGrades
            ,Case When  RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(GR.Reporting__c,';',''))) 
                  = RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(SY.CTEGrades,',','')))
                Then 'Matched'
                Else 'NOT Matched' END As Comments
            from #SFDC_GradeReport GR
            Full Outer Join #CoreSchoolYear SY
            on GR.SCH_Id = SY.SchoolID 
            and RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(GR.Reporting__c,';','')))  = 
             RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(SY.CTEGrades,',','')))
            Where (GR.SCH_Id is null OR SY.SchoolID is  null) 
            And GR.SCH_Id <> '005'
            And ((RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(SY.CTEGrades,',',''))) IS not NULL 
            OR RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(GR.Reporting__c,';','')))  IS not NULL))
            ) as s
```

ORDER BY SCH_Id,SchoolID
For xml Path('tr'), type,root('root') ) as nvarchar(max) )
select @body
print @body

IF @body IS NOT NULL -- Records found, send email.
BEGIN
--SELECT  @body
set @body =  '
'
+ 'EnrollMent_Year_New__cSCH_IdSchool NameReporting__cSchoolYearSchoolIDCTEGradesComments '
+ replace( replace( @body, '<', '<' ), '>', '>' )
+ ' 
'
Print @body
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = @profilename,
@recipients = @to,
@subject = @subject,
@body = @body,
@body_format ='HTML'

END
ELSE
BEGIN
PRINT @SuccessMessage
END
END

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: What data is in the #temp table? What XML output do you expect to render from it? Do you have `set concat_null_yields_null on`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have valid XML and inform the SQL engine about your data type.

1. Valid XML: you are missing an opening tag `<td>` at the start.
2. Data type: cast the string value to the `XML` data type.

I do not have your data from `#temp` to work with, so I replaced `S.*` with the field name string in my example.

```
SELECT
  CAST(      -- cast to XML data type (part 1)
  '<td>' +   -- add missing opening tag
  CAST('EnrollMent' AS varchar(30)) +'</td><td>' + 
  CAST('SCH_Id' AS varchar(30)) + '</td><td>' + 
  CAST('SchoolName' AS varchar(100)) + '</td><td>' + 
  CAST('Reporting_c' AS varchar(80)) + '</td><td>' + 
  CAST('SchoolYear' AS varchar(30)) + '</td><td>' + 
  CAST('SchoolID' AS varchar(30)) + '</td><td>' + 
  CAST('CTEGrades' AS varchar(80)) + '</td><td>' + 
  CAST('Comments' AS varchar(80)) + '</td>'
  AS XML)    -- cast to xml data type (part 2)
FOR XML PATH('row'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
```

This gives me:

```
<root><row><td>EnrollMent</td><td>SCH_Id</td><td>SchoolName</td><td>Reporting_c</td><td>SchoolYear</td><td>SchoolID</td><td>CTEGrades</td><td>Comments</td></row></root>
```

Or with some formatting:

```
<root>
   <row>
      <td>EnrollMent</td>
      <td>SCH_Id</td>
      <td>SchoolName</td>
      <td>Reporting_c</td>
      <td>SchoolYear</td>
      <td>SchoolID</td>
      <td>CTEGrades</td>
      <td>Comments</td>
   </row>
</root>
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/94156)

If this is not what you are trying to achieve, then please update your question with the expected output.